# Is there a way to check android version running the game using Unity3D?

Tags: unity, android

I want to separate code to run only on android 4.4 or higher. If it's lower, I do not want to run  this code. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ready to use method which is better than SystemInfo.operatingSystem :

```
public int GetSDKLevel() {
    var clazz = AndroidJNI.FindClass("android/os/Build$VERSION");
    var fieldID = AndroidJNI.GetStaticFieldID(clazz, "SDK_INT", "I");
    var sdkLevel = AndroidJNI.GetStaticIntField(clazz, fieldID);
    return sdkLevel;
}
```

Just copy and paste and that's all.

Note that if dots are uses instead of slashes as separators in the class name, it will crash in debuggable builds.

Comment: It won't crash in release (production) builds -  all you'll see is a runtime warning "Call to JNI FindClass with dots in name: android.os.Build$VERSION" and FindClass() behaves as expected, i.e. it is smart enough to handle this common JNI mistake.  It will however abort() in a debuggable app. I'm pretty sure this answer got copy-pasted into Unity's android runtime (libunity.so) cos that's what I'm seeing right now. Very very annoying cos I cannot fix 3rd party code.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [SystemInfo.operatingSystem](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-operatingSystem.html). The string should contain both OS name and version. Never tried on Android but should work.